# SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction by Magento position

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a problem in our Magento shop when we try to set the position of the products in a category from manage categories. When we try to save a product after changing the position in "category products" we get the following failure:

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying
>   to get lock; try restarting transaction

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: There is a long thread about this issue here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19472/

Comment: Magento have a lot to answer for when they scrapped the old forums and broke all these links.

Comment: Since the link above seems to be down: http://web.archive.org/web/20141001230241/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19472/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error occurs most probably because you have the product position index set to auto and Magento tries to rebuild the index along with the product save.
Go to `System->Index Management` and set the indexes related to catalog to 'manual'.
Then set the product positions and when you are done rebuild the indexes manually.

Comment: Which index do you mean with the product position index? If I am correct it is standard for magento to update the index on save and in all our other shops we can just set the position, so how can it be that we should set this one to manual? let me know

Comment: @Coen. I'm talking about the `Category Products` index. You are right, the index on save is standard, but sometimes because of high traffic and high volume of data to process this error can occur. Like I said this is 'probably' the reason. I said it from experience. I had the same issue and setting the index to manual update solved my problem.

Comment: @ Marius, Thanks that one worked for me, and will change it for the position and after that back again. Still strange that he does it that way, but it does the trick!

Comment: Hello @Marius, I faced same execption in "Payment Transaction Failed" email, while order for a specific product, What should I do?

Comment: Updated *'index_process'* table mode to *manual*, disabled indexer cron, killed already running process and ran the one which had issues `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product` few times until it said success. Restored settings back to `real_time`.