# Serialization failure: Deadlock found when trying to get lock

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting below error when there is multiple update is running particular table
Data base - Mysql - innodb engine
Language PHP- PDO

Error - Serialization failure: Deadlock found when trying to get lock

I checked below link 
[SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction by Magento position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040460/sqlstate40001-serialization-failure-1213-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-l)

Comment: post output from - 

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Comment: I was not able to get status. We had started mysql database.

Comment: its ok in mysql : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this link [Deadlock exception code for PHP, MySQL PDOException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368561/deadlock-exception-code-for-php-mysql-pdoexception/12375049#12375049) to handle the error, or you may want to simply try again.

MySQL tells you another update is running on the data that you want to update. So doesn't let you to do it.

And for more information about deadlocks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: This question is 18 months old. And it's not even a *question*. It's a *story*.

Comment: I didn't noticed the date, you're right. But going to leave it here if anyone needs it.